# Ruby on Rails - NameError: uninitialized constant User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, activerecord

Haven't used Rails in a while and just cloned a project, trying to work with the database but I'm getting this uninitialized constant error and I can't seem to figure out why. I bundle installed, created the database, migrated and seeded some files but I can't seem to find the root of the issue. It's not a small project and it seemed to be working fine back when I used it... Any help would be appreciated it...

Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
gem 'httparty'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'semantic-ui-sass', git: 'https://github.com/doabit/semantic-ui-sass.git'
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'pg_search'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'faker'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

And here's the User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :first_name, :last_name, :presence => true
  validates :username, :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  has_many :messages
  has_many :posts, :foreign_key => :creator_id
  has_many :apprenticeships, :foreign_key => :requestor_id
  has_many :skills, through: :posts

  has_secure_password

  def full_name
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end

end
```

I have also tried checking if tables were created with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` but I'm still getting `NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord`

Comment: So I can play with the database if I use `rails console --sandbox`, wasn't there a way I could access the database directly using `irb` or `pry`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `rails console` not `irb` or `pry` when working within a Ruby on Rails project. Rails has a complicated bootstrap process, and many of its classes are lazily loaded. Generic interactive consoles like `irb` or `pry` do not perform the necessary bootstrap to load a rails app,  but `rails console` will.